# Fuzzy shadow + pattern with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

When I try to run the following example from TikZ Manual for Version 2.10 on page 171 using TikZEdt, I get the following error:

```
Package pgf Error: Undefined fading: 'circle with fuzzy edge 20 percent,', \node [button] at (2.2,1) {\Huge Big};
```

Actually, I would like to get the effects on the 'Small' circle. How may I go about this?

Example Code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
[
% Define an interesting style
button/.style={
% First preaction: Fuzzy shadow
preaction={fill=black,path fading=circle with fuzzy edge 20 percent,
opacity=.5,transform canvas={xshift=1mm,yshift=-1mm}},
% Second preaction: Background pattern
preaction={pattern=#1,
path fading=circle with fuzzy edge 15 percent},
% Third preaction: Make background shiny
preaction={top color=white,
bottom color=black!50,
shading angle=45,
path fading=circle with fuzzy edge 15 percent,
opacity=0.2},
% Fourth preaction: Make edge especially shiny
preaction={path fading=fuzzy ring 15 percent,
top color=black!5,
bottom color=black!80,
shading angle=45},
inner sep=2ex
},
button/.default=horizontal lines light blue,
circle
]
\draw [help lines] (0,0) grid (4,3);
\node [button] at (2.2,1) {\Huge Big};
\node [button=crosshatch dots light steel blue,
text=white] at (1,1.5) {Small};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need the `patterns` and `fadings` libraries:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,fadings}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[
% Define an interesting style
button/.style={
% First preaction: Fuzzy shadow
preaction={fill=black,path fading=circle with fuzzy edge 20 percent,
opacity=.5,transform canvas={xshift=1mm,yshift=-1mm}},
% Second preaction: Background pattern
preaction={pattern=#1,
path fading=circle with fuzzy edge 15 percent},
% Third preaction: Make background shiny
preaction={top color=white,
bottom color=black!50,
shading angle=45,
path fading=circle with fuzzy edge 15 percent,
opacity=0.2},
% Fourth preaction: Make edge especially shiny
preaction={path fading=fuzzy ring 15 percent,
top color=black!5,
bottom color=black!80,
shading angle=45},
inner sep=2ex
},
button/.default=horizontal lines light blue,
circle
]
\draw [help lines] (0,0) grid (4,3);
\node [button] at (2.2,1) {\Huge Big};
\node [button=crosshatch dots light steel blue,
text=white] at (1,1.5) {Small};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you SOOOOO MUCH! I was goin crazy trying to figure out what was missing. Thanks