# How to add a gradient fade-out effect to an image?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, graphics, backgrounds

I am working on a presentation in beamer and would like to put a logo in the background of the title page with a gradient fade-out effect, similar to the image below. The logo is in PDF format and is in full-shape.

[image]

Comment: You can achieve a similar effect on your personal logo in application such as Illutrator of Inkscape. This is not done directly within beamer.

Comment: Sure, though I am under impression that it can also be done using TikZ quite simply.

Comment: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/transparent-png-overlay/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

With WriteLaTeX's `frog.jpg`, also in https://www.writelatex.com/542861kyqykv

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}


\setbeamertemplate{background}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path (0,0) rectangle (\paperwidth,\paperheight);
\node[scope fading=west,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,anchor=north east] at(\paperwidth,\paperheight) {\includegraphics[height=\paperheight]{frog.jpg}};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\author{Kermit}
\title{Autobiography}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your answer reminds of that question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112538/can-fuzzy-borders-be-added-to-external-pictures-programmatically. Would there be a way of superimposing multiple facings in different directions?

Comment: @Jubobs Should be possible within a transparency group.

Comment: How do you do the same, but with a fading to the South or, even better South East? With me the image becomes all white when you replace "west" by "south"

Comment: @percusse, How would you put it only first page?