# Fade out background pic without beamer

Tags: backgrounds, article

I am writing a technical report with a background figure on the cover. I want to add a fade-out effect to the image and I have found this  answer [How to add a gradient fade-out effect to an image?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147180/how-to-add-a-gradient-fade-out-effect-to-an-image/147185) but with the beamer class.

Is there a way to have the same effect with the article class?

My MWE is the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,titlepage]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\newcommand\BackgroundPic{%
\put(0,0){%
\parbox[b][\paperheight]{\paperwidth}{%
\vfill
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight,%
keepaspectratio]{Textura.pdf}%
\vfill
}}}

\begin{document} 
\begin{titlepage}
\AddToShipoutPicture*{\BackgroundPic}
\end{titlepage}
HOLA

\end{document}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the same code as in the `beamer` example. The relevant piece of code is the `tikzpicture` environment, where the image and the fade-out is specified. This code uses the `tikz` package and the `fadings` library for TikZ, which you have to add in the preamble (at the start of the code, between the documentclass and `\begin{document}`).

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,titlepage]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\newcommand\BackgroundPic{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path (0,0) rectangle (\paperwidth,\paperheight);
\node[scope fading=west,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,anchor=north east] at(\paperwidth,\paperheight) {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight,keepaspectratio]{example-image-c}};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document} 
\begin{titlepage}
\AddToShipoutPicture*{\BackgroundPic}
\end{titlepage}
HOLA

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]