# Setting a gradient fade-out effect only on the title page

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, graphics, backgrounds

I'm trying to adapt the code below so that the gradient fade-out effect appears only on the first page (title page).

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}

\setbeamertemplate{background}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path (0,0) rectangle (\paperwidth,\paperheight);
\node[scope fading = west, inner sep = 0pt, outer sep = 0pt, anchor = north east, opacity = .15] at(\paperwidth,\paperheight) {\includegraphics[height = \paperheight]{figures/ufpel.png}};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\title[Aula do dia 12/02/2019 \hspace{3.6cm}\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber]{Oferta e Demanda Agregada}
\subtitle[]{}
\author[Prof. Alexandre Loures - Economia/UFPel]{Prof. Alexandre Loures}
\institute{Departamento de Economia\\Universidade Federal de Pelotas}
\date{Concurso Métodos Quantitativos em Economia}

\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[width = 2.5cm]{figures/ufpel.png}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Original discussion in: [How to add a gradient fade-out effect to an image?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147180/how-to-add-a-gradient-fade-out-effect-to-an-image/147185)

Here is an image of how I wish the title page to be (only the title page will look like this).

[image]

Here's how the second page is getting.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you gave us no MWE I had to guess what you are doing. Please next question add a compilable tex code.

To get rid of the background image simply define a new empty background after `\maketitle`.

Please see the MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}


\setbeamertemplate{background}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path (0,0) rectangle (\paperwidth,\paperheight);
\node[scope fading=west,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,anchor=north east] at(\paperwidth,\paperheight) {\includegraphics[height=\paperheight]{higgs}};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[width = 2.5cm]{higgs}}

\author{username}
\title{Das Gottes-Teilchen}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}

\setbeamertemplate{background}{} % <====================================
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

and the resulting pages:

[image: titlepage]

and

[image: second page]

BTW: the picture `higgs.png` is taken [from here](https://www.spektrum.de/fm/912/thumbnails/CMS-PHO-EVENTS-2011-008-3.png.4818220.png).